# Pathfinding 2D Java game?

Tags: java, path, path-finding

I'm currently writing a very basic Java game based on the idea of *[Theme Hospital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theme_Hospital)*.

I'm quite new to Java and am currently studying at the university my first year. I have done Java for nearly two years now on and off, but I'm finally devoting my time to a decent project.

I'm at the stage where I need to create a person (patient) to be admitted to the hospital. They need to go to the reception desk, then GP's office, and then back to their starting position.

I have looked into A* path finding, but it seems really complicated to me. I understand how it works I think, but am unsure how to implement it into my game.

So far, the user can place a reception desk, and build a GP's office. Each of these has a "point of usage" which will be the place the patient has to get to. The grid squares can only be full or not, there will be no different terrain.

I'm hesitant to paste any code yet, as it's messy as I've learn a lot of new techniques to do with GUI in the past few months. My plan is to get to the milestone 1, making the patient go to the desk then the office and then leave. Once I have this, I will tidy up the code more.

I've seen many implementations of A* and many different types. Can someone give me a starting point I can work with? Should I try and adapt an already written set of classes, or try to write my own from the scratch?

Comment: see my post for the link to an A* implementation.

Comment: Great question, helps me a lot! However, I think this question will be flaged to be closed in stack overflow 2020 since some people see no code in the post :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do want A*, it is the optimal implementation for grid based pathfinding.

This might help you out:

http://www.cokeandcode.com/main/tutorials/path-finding/

**EDIT:** The preceeding link is good for both as an implementable set of classes and as a guide for customizing the path finding methods to meet your satisfaction.

Comment: Ah yes, i found this months ago when first researching stuff for my game idea. I will re read it, see if it helps. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Naturally you will learn a lot about pathfinding if you write your own implementation. But you will also spend a lot of time doing it.

Check out the [JGraphT](http://jgrapht.sourceforge.net/) library that deals with graphs in general, has a nice API and supports [more](http://www.jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/alg/DijkstraShortestPath.html) shortest path algorithms than just A*.

Answer (score 4):

This is the most informative pathfinding post I've seen to date: http://www.ai-blog.net/archives/000152.html

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken. It redirects to the main page of that site.

Answer (score 3):

The book [AI for Game Developers](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596005559/) has a very good explanation of A*.  I was actually going to write an implementation today... if I do I'll throw the code up here.

The code is done, it is too big to put here, so you can grab it from:   https://chaos.bcit.ca/svn/public/astar/ (self signed certificate, but the server doesn't do anything evil).

I followed the pseudo-code in the book for the most part, but I made everything much more object oriented than anything I have seen thus far for A*.

You have a Maze that consists of Tiles.  Each Tile has a Location and an Obstacle (null if there is no obstacle).

You can use a PathFinder (like AStar) to find th shortest path between a given start and end location.  You get a Path back which includes the Tiles you need to go through to get from the start to the end.

You can change the heuristic calculation by providing a different HeuristicCalculator (the current one just checks to see if there is an Obstacle or not and figures out the shortest number of Tiles to go through, you could add weights to different Obstacles for instance if you don't like the default).

The code is license under the LGPL, so if you make changes and distribute the app you have to make the changes available.  Feel free to send bug reports/fixes to the email address in the license comment (found in each header).

I'll (never did) get around to commenting it after exams, but I think it is pretty straight forward.

Comment: wow i like SO, very fast responses.
Thanks, that would be awesome if you did.
If I did use your implementation, I would of course give you full credit!

Comment: no worries (only a few former students know my real name here anyways :-)

Comment: As long as you post something interesting, broad, or cool you'll get fast responses.  Precise technical questions in areas that not many people have experience with, or badly written questions with few details and you'll see the quieter side of SO.  :)

Comment: Code has been posted (see link)

Comment: The link isn't accessible.

Comment: Yeah... I switched offices a while back, and am about to again. I'll see about getting it up and running again after the move.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you found what you wanted, but here's a link with a nice explanation of A* pathfinding. I had to implement A* for my game in [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B), and it helped me a lot to understand how it works.

http://www.abdn.ac.uk/~csc245/teaching/CS1015/practicals/aStarTutorial.htm

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken: *You don't have permission to access /~csc245/teaching/CS1015/practicals/aStarTutorial.htm on this server.*