# Are there any approaches for beginner pathfinding in java in a set grid?

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to design a game revolving a AI chasing you. I want him to always find the shortest route torwards the player. I'm still relatively novice at java and I have never done pathfinding before, so are there any approaches you would suggest for pathfinding inside a grid (etc. 3x3 - 5x5) Additionally, I am trying to add a command that makes the AI always prioritize a certain direction if there are multiple ways of getting to the target that have equivalent distance to them. Is there a simple approach to this? I don't want to make it too complicated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Comment: I think that you'll find usefull information on this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735523/pathfinding-2d-java-game